# Failed to convert parameter value from a DropDownList to a String

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, database

I here trying to make dropdownlist value insert into my `sqldatabase` but it does not work. Can you help me find what I did wrong?

This some my asp.net code for dropdownlist:

```
<p> Hardware Type&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; :
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="17px" Width="128px">
        <asp:ListItem>Please Choose</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="laptop">Laptop</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="server">Server</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="television">Television</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="printer">Printer</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

this some my .cs for dropdownlist

```
comu.Parameters.Add("Hwtype", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
comu.Parameters["Hwtype"].Value = DropDownList1;
comu.Connection = con;
comu.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
}
}
```

i get this error : `Failed to convert parameter value from a DropDownList to a String.`

Comment: It should be `comu.Parameters["Hwtype"].Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;`

Comment: Please google your questions before you post on SO, This question is very basic for using asp.net dropdown list.

Comment: @Usama Khalil yes, i think i need head back to tutorial.. sorry sometime i forget thing.. getting old...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** You are trying to assign the `DropDownList` control instead of it's `SelectedValue`.

Replace This:

```
comu.Parameters["Hwtype"].Value = DropDownList1;
```

With This:

```
comu.Parameters["Hwtype"].Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```

OR

```
comu.Parameters["Hwtype"].Value = DropDownList1.Items[DropDownList1.SelectedIndex];
```

Comment: Please google your answer before asking your question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Usama Khalil i did google them.. but most coding was not exactly same like i did... so it hard to understand some others advance code then the basic code like i did... please understand thanks you.